# How to set types for a function which is as function argument and can have any arguments and any returns

Tags: typescript

I want to write a debounce function with typescript. My code is shown below:

```js
function debounce(fn: Function, time: number): Function {
  // ...
}
```

And then, my `eslint` tell me don't use `Function` as a type. Below is original text:

Don't use `Function` as a type. The `Function` type accepts any function-like value.
It provides no type safety when calling the function, which can be a common source of bugs.
It also accepts things like class declarations, which will throw at runtime as they will not be called with `new`.

If you are expecting the function to accept certain arguments, you should explicitly define the function shape.

That's the problem, any suggestion?

==================== Some update ==================================

If use javascript, my code will be:

```js
function debounce(fn, time) {
  let timer
  return function (...args) {
    clearTimeout(timer)
    timer = setTimeout(() => fn(...args), time)
  }
}
```

Comment: make it [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), probably?  Can you give a toy implementation of `debounce`?  You're not returning the same function exactly, and what you return would have some effect on the correct call signature.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/wO8brN) meet your needs? If not, please [edit] your question with a [mre] that shows the failing use cases.  If it does meet your needs I can write up an answer.

Comment: Thanks for comment, I add a simple example, please take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you look into TypeScript's [utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html), such as `Parameters<Type>` and `ThisParameterType<Type>`. They're what I used for [my TypeScript implementation of a debounce function](https://github.com/Cipscis/debounce/blob/main/src/debounce.ts) to make the returned function match the signature of the input function.

As for how I specified the function argument, I used generics like this:

```
const debounce = function<T extends (...args: any) => any> (fn: T, delay: number) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's really helpful. And I also saw your implementation with Promise, it's very interesting 

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad to hear it's helpful. My implementation started off much more like yours, but when I was converting it to TypeScript I was also thinking if there was any way I could enhance it, and I decided I didn't like how the return value of the debounced function was being lost. As you can see though, it adds a fair amount of complexity to an otherwise relatively simple solution, and for most implementations I'm sure it won't be needed.

Answer (score 4):

Given your implementation, the function returned from `debounce()` does not return a useful result; that means we don't care what the return type of the `fn` argument is.  In this case, I'd probably make `debounce()` a [generic function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) with a type parameter `A` as a [rest tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#generic-rest-parameters) corresponding to the arguments to `fn`.  Like this:

```
function debounce<A extends any[]>(fn: (...a: A) => void, time: number) {
    let timer: number;
    return function (...args: A) {
        clearTimeout(timer)
        timer = setTimeout(() => fn(...args), time)
    }
}
```

The type `(...a: A) => void` is a [function type expression](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-type-expressions), meaning "a function whose arguments array is of type `A` and which returns `void` so [its return type will be ignored](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#return-type-void)".

If you inspect the type of `debounce()`, it looks like this:

```
/* function debounce<A extends any[]>(
     fn: (...a: A) => void, time: number
   ): (...args: A) => void */
```

So it takes a function of type `(...a: A) => void` and it returns a function of the same type.

---

Let's make sure it works:

```
function log(x: string) {
    console.log(x);
}

const debouncedLog = debounce(log, 1000);

debouncedLog("hello");
debouncedLog(100); // error, doesn't accept a number
debouncedLog("there");
// just "there" is logged
```

You can see that the compiler complains about `debouncedLog(100)` because `100` is not assignable to `string`, while the other calls work.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.3#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEwKYCM7gqgPAQUVQA8pUxkBnRAQzAE8BtAXQD4AKYMALkXYDpBNXvgCUiALytEANzgxkAGkSwAtql5gQq9KgBO4gN4BYAFCILiADaooKmOr2btuvQG4zlxHtsg9SUEhYBD5Bfho9AHNKESNPL0sIGwiAFQdULCh2NX1ReIT7R0lESls09Uz2dnEpRC4BISjKUWUcvPNLAF8zbtMzAHoAKjrsYKQ0TGw8QhIyCmo6JjZOHlChWMlpOQVW9OcdXN4G8KaN2u3kREH+s1vTQOh4JCs4SPZiXkooPRgwSLiOhYIAhKHAbPwXm9iKIPKZemZgWAvigMFhIKhkAAZV7FCZonDsSHKACMAAZyTC7nipljXuwAEQAC1QVhe9Mppmp6NpbzJpJhiH6-SIej0cD0ymQcFQlDAAHI7DQIDgAA6KxBaA56MxcnA8hlQZk+dmwoWIABWIGR9MN+lQ9MQMGokMiGLuQA)